# Set System Property in Gradle command line

Tags: gradle

I am new to gradle. I would like to pass a variable in gradle from comand line. Something similar to maven as shown below.

`mvn clean install -Denvironment=DEV`

And I get the above `environment=DEV` value in java as

`System.getProperty("environment")`

How Is it possible to do the same thing in Gradle? Is there any quick and easy way like in maven?